# Запятая после слова "может"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после слова "может"?
Пример: Может зря не просили мы снисхождения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна, поскольку **может** здесь вводное слово со значением "неуверенность". Пример предложения, в котором слово **может** входит в составное сказуемое и не требует обособления: "Он может просить снисхождения".